# understanding ruby class attributes, using accessor macros and self

Tags: ruby

So I create a class in ruby:

```
class User
  def initialize
  end
end
```

Now say I want to create a attribute that is a hash with a getter/setter, I'm confused as to the options I have doing this.

If I do this:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :some_hash
end
```

But I don't want this hash to be nil ever, always an empty hash.

I'm confused when I should do:

```
def some_hash
  self.some_hash ||= {}
end
```

and do:

```
def some_hash
  @some_hash ||= {}
end
```

What is the difference?

If I don't use the attr_accessor, I have to create both the reader and writer (or getter/setter):

```
def some_hash=()
end

def some_hash
end
```

**I'm hoping someone can clear up the options I would have for creating a some_hash attribute which is a hash, and that never returns a nil if it is empty.**

i.e. using attr_accessor, manually creating the methods, and finally when to use @some_hash and self.some_hash

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`attr_accessor :some_hash` defines reader and writer methods for the given attribute. It is equivalent to this:

```
class User
  def some_hash
    @some_hash
  end

  def some_hash=(a_hash)
    @some_hash = a_hash
  end
end
```

`@some_hash` refers to an instance variable of the object, while `some_hash` and `some_hash=` are *methods*. The former returns the value of the variable, the latter sets it.

The idiom `self.some_hash ||= {}` is equivalent to `self.some_hash || self.some_hash = {}`.

Boolean operators in Ruby [short circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), which means the second expression (`self.some_hash = {}`) will not be executed at all if the first expression (`self.some_hash`) returns a true value.

The method:

```
def some_hash
  self.some_hash ||= {}
end
```

Is actually recursive, since it expands to `some_hash || self.some_hash = {}`. It will keep calling itself until you get a stack overflow. Use the second form:

```
def some_hash
  @some_hash ||= {}
end
```

Since it sets the instance variable directly, you will not have problems with recursion, nor will you have to call a writer method. `some_hash` can never return `nil`, because if `@some_hash` is `nil`, it will be assigned an empty hash before the method returns.

By the way, this is also called [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization), because the variable is initialized when it is first accessed, not when the `User` instance is created.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from Matheus's answer, a little more about attributes:

Attributes are methods. They define how you do with some symbols. `attr_reader` defines the getter, `attr_writer` defines the setter and `attr_accessor` defines both. While attributes only take symbols, it does not "declare" any instance variables, as there is no such a thing in Ruby as declaring a variable. It is always declared and initialized when the first time used.

So after you say, `attr_accessor :some_hash`, the runtime will know the way to access a variable called `some_hash`, but this variable does not exist till you use it. You can try:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :some_hash
  attr_reader :some_other_hash
end
usr = User.new
p usr.some_hash

usr.some_hash = {}
p usr.some_hash

p usr.some_other_hash
usr.some_other_hash = {}
```

You will get `nil,{},nil, and an error`. The error is because only getter method is defined but no setter. If you want to define a setter yourself, you can still write a method called `some_other_hash=()`

My suggestion for instance variable is (which I and maybe many others use):

```
class User
  attr_accessor :some_hash

  def initialize
    @some_hash = {}
  end

end
usr = User.new
p usr.some_hash
```

This way does a "psudo" declaration when you create an object for the class, and the instance variable will also be initialized.

Comment: Using your last example, what if I add another method to the `User` class called `print_me`, should I use `@some_hash` or `some_hash` inside the method to access the variable in context? I mean: `def print_me; puts @some_hash; end` or `def print_me; puts some_hash; end`. I hope I'm enough clear on my example!