# How can I create a class/object that does not need to be stored in a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is creating a model that does not extend ActiveRecord the way to do this? e.g.

```
class Shipment
end
```

And if I do this do I need to define properties, or can I simply do:

```
shipment = Shipment.new
shipment.weight = 7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally in **OOP** you can define a class and inheritance is an option.

In Rails (ruby) you can define a class without extending `ActiveRecord`

So this:

```
class Shipment
end
```

is a **valid** ruby class, and you can initiate an object from it using `shipment = Shipment.new` as you guessed

However if you try:

```
shipment.weight = 7
```

You will get `Undefined method 'weight' for shipment` which does make sense , right? because you never defined some way to set a `weight` attribute for the `Shipment` class!

You should define a `weight` setter or getter or both and ruby makes it super easy to do so:

```
class Shipment
  attr_accessor :weight
end
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
class Shipment
  #getter
  def weight
    #return the weight
    @weight
  end

  #setter
  def weight=(weight)
    #set the weight
    @weight = weight
  end
end
```

#### Reading links:

1. Ruby docs (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Class.html)
2. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737421/trying-to-learn-understand-ruby-setter-and-getter-methods) explains how setter and getter works in ruby
3. Both answers to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809843/understanding-ruby-class-attributes-using-accessor-macros-and-self) are useful (understanding ruby classes, attributes)

Comment: Thanks for going into detail!

Comment: You are welcome :) i just had the same questions some time ago

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create non active record model by creating a class within your application.

You will still need to define the properties of that class that you would like it have, as with any other.

Ryan Bates has a short screencast about the topic at:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/121-non-active-record-model